# Quantum group symmetry in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, group-theory, representation-theory

In Wikipedia article [Coleman–Mandula theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem) there's statement:

> Quantum group symmetry, present in some two-dimensional integrable quantum field theories like the sine-Gordon model, exploits a similar loophole.

**Are some examples of quantum group symmetry in $d≥3$? Or there are arguments, why this symmetry can be realised only in 2d?**